# What will happen to the object inside a method after the method will load in stack?

Tags: java, memory-management

My idea in the Java memory management is not fully clear.

We know that methods will load in stack and objects in heap.

eg.

```
method() {
   ExampleClass ec=new ExampleClass();
}
```

Now when the method will load in stack, what will happen to the object? will it be automatically excluded from the method and will load in the heap ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "methods will load in stack" to start with?

Comment: Method lives in stack, right?

Comment: @Reuben: What exactly do you mean by that, in concrete terms? The more concrete you try to make your thoughts, the clearer they're likely to become.

Comment: @Reuben: What do you expect to be in that memory? The bytecode? The JIT-compiled code? Why would the code need to be on the stack?

Comment: @Reuben: the stack contains the return address where the method was invoked from, and the parameters to the method, and NOT the whole method in bytecode, maybe that's where you are confused?

Comment: @Jon When the class will load a memory will allocate for the method in the stack. So my question is, does it mean that whatever the method contains will go to stack ?

Comment: @Amit In the stack there are also the local variables

Comment: Down Voter Can't I clarify my drawbacks? Is it a forum for experienced persons only? I don't know that's why I asked .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

What will be loaded in the stack is the reference to the object. Same if you pass the method as a parameter.

The fact that Java does not have pointers like C or C++ does not mean that they are not there. It is just that (apart from primitives) they are everywhere.

Comment: +1: Java only has references (or primitives) so there is no need for & and * notation like in C/C++., this is assumed.